XSD Ordering with possible multiple child element
I'm trying to create an XDS for an XML to describe a family. Basically a Mum/Dad being optional and comming in any order, and 0-* children. In this instance you can have the following
<family>
      <DadsName>Fred</DadsName>
      <MumsName>Wilma</MumsName>
        <child>
           <childName>pebbles</childName>
        </child>
        <child>
           <childName>BamBam</childName>
        </child>
</family>

In this msg the mum/dad names can come in any order, and some times they are optional -> This is important
I've created the following XSD..
<xs:element name="family">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="DadsName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="MumsName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="child"  maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="childName" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="childAge" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

I specifically added the <xs:all> as the ordering of Mum and Dad can be jumbled, and the elements are optional as well.
Is this correct? I get the error 'The maxOccurs attribute is invalid. The value unBounded is invalid according to its datatype Union'

Which XSD validator do you use? Can you use XSD 1.1?

It looks like you are using an XSD 1.0 processor: what you have written is valid in XSD 1.1. You either need to find an XSD 1.1 processor, or change your aspirations: what you are trying to do can't be defined in 1.0.
